# Is it normal for a variable, in VB.NET, to retain its value between page transactions?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

Is it normal for some variables not to have been reset and still retain their value 
after a page transaction, 
and also even after browser was closed but immediately re-opened and same web page re-browsed?

In my VB ASP.NET web app, user performs several steps.

I discovered a bug where after final step, if user refreshes page a couple times,
then closes browser (IE11),
then opens new browser and goes to site,
when Page_load() is called visual basic variables are sometimes not reset, and still have previous value from when page was previously browsed.

Comment: It would really help if you'd show some code... for example, if the variable is `Shared` that would explain it.

Comment: Are you using Session or Cookie variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where the state for that variable is tracked.

If the variable is scoped locally to a method, then no it won't still be the same.  Once the method is finished, the value is lost.

If the variable is an instance value on an object, it will be retained as long as that object is in memory.  Once the object is disposed (usually when no variable references it anymore), the value is lost.

If the variable is static (`Shared` in VB) then it's scoped to the app domain.  It will continue to hold its value as long as the application is running.  Once the application exits, the value is lost.

If the variable is kept in session then it will retain its value until the session is ended (either in code, usually by the user logging out, or by the application exiting).  Once the session is ended, the value is lost.

If the variable is populated from a cookie then it exists on the client machine and will be supplied to the application any time that client accesses the application.  Cookie expiration can be set when creating the cookie, and once it expires the value is lost.

If the variable is populated from some external persistence (such as a database) then it will retain its value until that persistence is changed.  The application can shut down, start again, even run on a different machine and the persistence still holds the value.

Look at your variable and determine its scope, that will tell you when it will lose its value.